# How do I get a list faster with an index relationship between two large size lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, performance

The question is given the following two lists.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

num = 100000

a = list(range(num))
b = [rnd.randint(0, num) for r in range(num)]
```

Between two lists with a huge size(assuming that the reference list is `a`), a list indicating where the same element is located in the relative array(`b`) was created using the list(`atob`) comprehension method.

```
atob = [np.abs(np.subtract(b, i)).argmin() for i in a]
print(f"index a to b: {atob}")
```

It doesn't take long when the list size is small. However, I realized that the process of obtaining the list `atob` is quite time consuming.

Is there a way to get list `atob` faster? Or is there currently no way?

---

(Edited after answering. The purpose of this revision is for future readers.)
Many thanks for the replies! Code analysis was conducted based on the answers.

- check the output

The comparison of results was performed with `num = 20`.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import time

# set lists
num = 20
a = list(range(num))
# b = [rnd.randint(0, num) for r in range(num)] # Duplicate numbers occur among the elements in the list
b = rnd.sample(range(0, num), num)
print(f"list a: {a}")
print(f"list b: {b}\n")

# set array as same as lists
arr_a = np.array(range(num))
arr_b = np.array(rnd.sample(range(0, num), num))

# --------------------------------------------------------- #
# existing method
ck_time = time.time()
atob = [np.abs(np.subtract(b, i)).argmin() for i in a]
print(f"index a to b (existed): {atob}, type: {type(atob)}")
print(f"running time (existed): {time.time() - ck_time}\n")
ck_time = time.time()

# dankal444 method
dk = {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate(b)}
atob_dk = [dk.get(n) for n in a] # same as atob_dk = [d.get(n) for n in range(num)]
print(f"index a to b (dankal): {atob_dk}, type: {type(atob_dk)}")
print(f"running time (dankal): {time.time() - ck_time}")
print(f"equal to exist method: {np.array_equal(atob, atob_dk)}\n")
ck_time = time.time()

# smp55 method
comb = np.array([a, b]).transpose()
atob_smp = comb[comb[:, 1].argsort()][:, 0]
print(f"index a to b (smp55): {atob_smp}, type: {type(atob_smp)}")
print(f"running time (smp55): {time.time() - ck_time}")
print(f"equal to exist method: {np.array_equal(atob, atob_smp)}\n")
ck_time = time.time()

# Roman method
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def find_argmin(_a, _b):
    out = np.empty_like(_a)  # allocating result array
    for i in range(_a.shape[0]):
        out[i] = np.abs(np.subtract(_b, _a[i])).argmin()
    return out

atob_rom = find_argmin(arr_a, arr_b)
print(f"index a to b (Roman): {atob_rom}, type: {type(atob_rom)}")
print(f"running time (Roman): {time.time() - ck_time}")
print(f"equal to exist method: {np.array_equal(atob, atob_rom)}\n")
ck_time = time.time()

# Alain method
from bisect import bisect_left
ub   = {n:-i for i,n in enumerate(reversed(b),1-len(b))}  # unique first pos
sb   = sorted(ub.items())                                 # sorted to bisect
ib   = (bisect_left(sb,(n,0)) for n in a)                 # index of >= val
rb   = ((sb[i-1],sb[min(i,len(sb)-1)]) for i in ib)       # low and high pairs
atob_ala = [ i if (abs(lo-n),i)<(abs(hi-n),j) else j      # closest index
               for ((lo,i),(hi,j)),n in zip(rb,a) ]
print(f"index a to b (Alain): {atob_ala}, type: {type(atob_ala)}")
print(f"running time (Alain): {time.time() - ck_time}")
print(f"equal to exist method: {np.array_equal(atob, atob_ala)}\n")
ck_time = time.time()

# ken method
b_sorted, b_sort_indices = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
def find_nearest(value):
    """Finds the nearest value from b."""
    right_index = np.searchsorted(b_sorted[:-1], value)
    left_index = max(0, right_index - 1)
    right_delta = b_sorted[right_index] - value
    left_delta = value - b_sorted[left_index]
    if right_delta == left_delta:
        # This is only necessary to replicate the behavior of your original code.
        return min(b_sort_indices[left_index], b_sort_indices[right_index])
    elif left_delta < right_delta:
        return b_sort_indices[left_index]
    else:
        return b_sort_indices[right_index]

atob_ken = [find_nearest(ai) for ai in a]
print(f"index a to b (ken): {atob_ken}, type: {type(atob_ken)}")
print(f"running time (ken): {time.time() - ck_time}")
print(f"equal to exist method: {np.array_equal(atob, atob_ken)}\n")
ck_time = time.time()
```

Above code result is

```
list a: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
list b: [9, 12, 0, 2, 3, 15, 4, 16, 13, 6, 7, 18, 14, 10, 1, 8, 5, 17, 11, 19]

index a to b (existed): [2, 14, 3, 4, 6, 16, 9, 10, 15, 0, 13, 18, 1, 8, 12, 5, 7, 17, 11, 19], type: <class 'list'>
running time (existed): 0.00024008750915527344

index a to b (dankal): [2, 14, 3, 4, 6, 16, 9, 10, 15, 0, 13, 18, 1, 8, 12, 5, 7, 17, 11, 19], type: <class 'list'>
running time (dankal): 1.5497207641601562e-05
equal to exist method: True

index a to b (smp55): [ 2 14  3  4  6 16  9 10 15  0 13 18  1  8 12  5  7 17 11 19], type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
running time (smp55): 0.00020551681518554688
equal to exist method: True

index a to b (Roman): [17 11  1  6 16 14  9  4  8  3  5 12  7  2 19 15 18 13  0 10], type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
running time (Roman): 0.5710980892181396
equal to exist method: False

index a to b (Alain): [2, 14, 3, 4, 6, 16, 9, 10, 15, 0, 13, 18, 1, 8, 12, 5, 7, 17, 11, 19], type: <class 'list'>
running time (Alain): 3.552436828613281e-05
equal to exist method: True

index a to b (ken): [2, 14, 3, 4, 6, 16, 9, 10, 15, 0, 13, 18, 1, 8, 12, 5, 7, 17, 11, 19], type: <class 'list'>
running time (ken): 0.00011754035949707031
equal to exist method: True
```

- Running time increasing list size

If I run the code with `num = 1000000`

```
running time (dankal): 0.45094847679138184

running time (smp55): 0.36011743545532227

running time (Alain): 2.178112030029297

running time (ken): 2.663684368133545
```

(With Roman's method, it was difficult to check the time when the size was increased.)

The memory point of view also needs to be checked, but first of all, the @smp55 method is the fastest way to obtain a list based on the required time in replies.(I'm sure there are other good ways.)

Once again, thank you all for your attention and replies!!!

(Subsequent replies and comments are also welcome. If anyone has a good idea, it would be nice to share!)

Comment: What do you mean by "faster" and "time consuming" ? We're missing some benchmark basis from your side. Someone may do the work for you in an answer, but when speaking about performance, one should try to give some factual elements to support claims and trigger a useful conversation. Facts, otherwise we may fall in the opinions ocean.

Comment: `np.subtract(b, i).argmin()` returns the same value every time. Is that the behavior you expected?

Comment: @LoneWanderer, When comparing the lists with the size of `num` in the example, the method I used did not yield results even after several minutes.
At around `num=1000`, the calculation result was immediately confirmed(just in time), so the running time did not give much meaning.

Comment: you could optimize it by sorting both arrays (keeping sorting indices) and iterate over both arrays at the same time. This way you wouldn't have to make big search for each value. That would be  O(n*logn) algorithm instead of O(n^2) algorithm you have now.

Comment: @ken, Oh! sorry... My mistake. Not `np.subtract(b, i).argmin()` → `np.abs(np.subtract(b, i)).argmin()`. I will correct the error in the text

Comment: @dankal444, How should I do it?

Comment: another idea: build dict to keep indices of b values, `b_value_to_idx = [value: idx for idx, value in enumerate(b)`

Comment: @dankal444, Is `value: idx` a valid logic in python? It's my first time seeing logic, so I'm really curious. Or just idea?

Comment: I made small mistake, I wrote list comprehension, while it should be dict comprehension: `{value: idx for idx, value in enumerate(b)}`. And yes, it is valid logic, even faster than simple for loop

Comment: Are `a` and `b` actual values you would use? At least `b` should be in a numpy array by adding `b = np.array(b)` before computing atob.

Comment: @ken, It was part of an algorithm I was envisioning. The ramdom part can be replaced with real values.(I declared `b` as random, but in reality there should be no duplicate numbers to enable one-to-one mapping.) The example was created randomly by me. Where should I `b = np.array(b)` add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a specific answer that is very fast based on the fact that your first list is simply an index. If you combine them in a 2D array, you can then sort by the second list, which will put the first list (indices of the second list) in the order of the result you want:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

num = 100000

a = list(range(num))
b = [rnd.randint(0, num) for r in range(num)]

comb = np.array([a, b]).transpose()
atob = comb[comb[:, 1].argsort()][:,0]
```

Takes ~0.08 seconds. Now, the first item in `atob` is the index in `b` where the first item in `a` appears. Second item in `atob` is the index in `b` of the second item of `a`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @dankal444 suggested in the comments section, sorting is a good approach. The following perfectly replicates the results of your code, but the execution time was about 0.25 seconds on my PC.

```py
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

num = 100000


a = list(range(num))
b = np.array([rnd.randint(0, num) for _ in range(num)])

# You can also create them with numpy like this.
# a = np.arange(num)
# b = np.random.randint(0, num, size=num)

# This will sort and remove duplicate items at the same time.
b_sorted, b_sort_indices = np.unique(b, return_index=True)


def find_nearest(value):
    """Finds the nearest value from b."""
    right_index = np.searchsorted(b_sorted[:-1], value)
    left_index = max(0, right_index - 1)
    right_delta = b_sorted[right_index] - value
    left_delta = value - b_sorted[left_index]
    if right_delta == left_delta:
        # This is only necessary to replicate the behavior of your original code.
        return min(b_sort_indices[left_index], b_sort_indices[right_index])
    elif left_delta < right_delta:
        return b_sort_indices[left_index]
    else:
        return b_sort_indices[right_index]


atob = [find_nearest(ai) for ai in a]
```

Maybe we can make this even faster by sorting `a` as well, but I don't know how fast you want it to be, so I'll leave this as my answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to build a list of `b` values associated with the index of their first occurrence.  Then sort these to allow a binary search (using bisect)

Using binary search on that sorted data, find the position of each value of `a`.  This will be the next higher value in b.

The previous item in the sorted list gives the value and position of the previous lower value.

Finally, select the index of the previous or next value depending on the difference with each number in `a`:

```
import random as rnd
from bisect import bisect_left
    
num = 10 # 0000

a = list(range(num))
b = [rnd.randint(0, num) for r in range(num)]


ub   = {n:-i for i,n in enumerate(reversed(b),1-len(b)) } # unique first pos
sb   = sorted(ub.items())                                 # allow bisect
ib   = ( bisect_left(sb,(n,0)) for n in a )               # index of >= val
lhb  = ( (sb[i-1],sb[min(i,len(sb)-1)]) for i in ib )     # low and high pairs
atob = [ i if (abs(lo-n),i)<(abs(hi-n),j) else j          # closest index
           for ((lo,i),(hi,j)),n in zip(lhb,a) ]

print(a)
print(b)
print(atob)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 1, 7, 9, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 10]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 0, 2, 2, 3]
```

Time for num=100000 is 0.19 second.

Time complexity is O(NlogN)

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd suggest using [`Numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode)(a just-in-time compiler for Python) to speed up `numpy` computations:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import jit
import random

num = 100000
a = np.array(range(num))
b = np.array([random.randint(0, num) for r in range(num)])

@jit(nopython=True)
def find_argmins(a, b):
    out = np.empty_like(a)  # allocating result array
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        out[i] = np.abs(np.subtract(b, a[i])).argmin()
    return out
```

Running:

```
find_argmins(a, b)
array([69772, 69772, 32964, ...,  7648, 92904,  4006])
```

Time performance (on humble virtual machine with 2 Gb of memory):

```
%timeit find_argmins(a, b)
12 s ± 739 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: `a = np.arange(num)`; `b = np.random.randint(0, num, num)`